# What are the ways to sort strings like "2001V001.10"?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

What are the ways to sort the below data in any order (ascending/descending) in java -

**Input -**

```
2002V001.10
2003V001.10
2004V001.20
2001V002.10
2004V001.10
2001V001.10
```

Where string before `.` is version and after `.` is sub-version, and both has to be considered while sorting.

**Expected output -**

```
2001V001.10
2001V002.10
2002V001.10
2003V001.10
2004V001.10
2004V001.20
```

Comment: What did you try? What doesn't work?

Comment: The data you've provided is so ambiguous, you should breakdown these strings and explain the possibilities that they could run into; before thinking about trying to sort them.

Comment: The natural ordering should be sufficient in your case. Try Before Asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your data to a treeset would sort it as you wanted.

**NOTE** : It removes duplicates.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<String> a = new TreeSet<String>();
        a.add("2001V001.10");
        a.add("2001V002.10");
        a.add("2002V001.10");
        a.add("2003V001.10");
        a.add("2004V001.10");
        a.add("2004V001.20");
        for (String string : a) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class like this:

```
public class StringsLike2001v001_10Comparator extends Comparator<String> {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // implement your ordering logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: for this use case natural ordering will work, no need of `Compartor`

Comment: So how will you sort in descending order without using a Comparator/Comparable type solution?

Comment: `Collections.reverse` can be used

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Or Collections.reverseOrder()

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort as String

```
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("2002V001.10", "2003V001.10", "2004V001.20", "2001V002.10", "2004V001.10",
            "2001V001.10");

    System.out.println(strings);
    Collections.sort(strings);
    System.out.println(strings);
```

output

before sort

```
[2002V001.10, 2003V001.10, 2004V001.20, 2001V002.10, 2004V001.10, 2001V001.10]
```

after sort

```
[2001V001.10, 2001V002.10, 2002V001.10, 2003V001.10, 2004V001.10, 2004V001.20]
```